# High CPU usage in Xcode 9.3

Tags: swift4, xcode9

Why is Xcode 9.3 eating up all the CPU when running playgrounds. It seems like “diagnostics” and “homed” are the two processes that are causing the fault. Apple seems to be really sleeping over this. No solution on the Apple developer website.
Is anyone also facing the same issue

Comment: You can try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49591847/xcode-9-3-playground-diagnosticd

Answer (score 0):

I updated the version of Xcode to 9.4 and this bugs was solved.

You can download xcode in this link:

[Download & Install Xcode 10 version without Premium Developer Account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44390162/download-install-xcode-10-version-without-premium-developer-account)

Comment: Hi Tiago, thanks for the reply. I have also updated to Xcode 9.4 and the problem got solved for me as well.